# Multiple event handlers on a single event.trigger or event.delegate?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm working on integrating PDF.JS with Aurelia, and I have two methods that I'd like to run in reaction to a `scroll` event. Generally, I would consolidate these two functions into one method. However, for my use case, I need to use a different binding behavior for each method.

I have a `renderHandler` that I would like to use with `scroll.trigger` like so:

```
<div ref="container" class="pdf-container" scroll.trigger="renderHandler() & debounce:250">
```

However, I also have another `scrollHandler` (which, instead of handling render events, will now only handle value binding updates, such as the page number while scrolling) that I'd like to use with the throttle behavior like this:

```
<div ref="container" class="pdf-container" scroll.trigger="scrollHandler & throttle">
```

Separately, these work. I'm not sure how to put them together. Aurelia currently doesn't allow multiple expressions inside of a `trigger` or `delegate` expression, and duplicating the property in the element has no effect (as the duplicate probably gets clobbered during Aurelia's parsing).

Is there a way to declaratively use two handlers with different binding behaviors for the same event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework currently does not support multiple event bindings for the same event, element and binding command combination.

As a workaround, you could add a `trigger2` binding command:

```js
import {SyntaxInterpreter} from 'aurelia-templating-binding';
SyntaxInterpreter.prototype.trigger2 = SyntaxInterpreter.prototype.trigger;
```

Then you would be able to use `scroll.trigger` and `scroll.trigger2` on the same element.

Example:

https://gist.run/?id=b51e1c0ff28de5d19d1018881399c4e4

Comment: I thought of something else today - I might be able to use `scroll.bind` to call one of the functions, as long as it doesn't need a binding behavior or an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what version it became available.
but this syntax works.

`<button click.delegate="[click1(), click2()]">multiple click handlers</button>`